# how to take url from a textfield which is to be filled by the user and view in new tab using html or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

this is the codeand its giving blank

```js
< div style = "position:"absolte ";align="center ";">
  Surf here: < input type = "text" id = "myText" value = "" >
  < br >
  < button onclick = "myFunction()" > Load < /button>
 <p id="demo"></p >
  < script >
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    var newwindow = window.open(x);
  } < /script>

 </div >
```

This i snot working help me out please !

Comment: you tried window.location = "href_given_by_the_user" ?

Answer (score 1):

I have make some changes in your code. Please use http also when type URL like http://www.google.co.in

```
<div style = "position:absolte;">
Surf here: <input type = "text"
id = "myText"
value = "" >
<br>
<button onclick = "myFunction()" > Load </button>
<p id="demo"></p >
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
var newwindow = window.open(x);
} </script>

</div>
```

Comment: You have unnecessary white spaces in your code pls use above code with example URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getURL(){
     window.location.href = document.getElementById("url").value   
}
```

Try with this code.

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, start typing url like `http://google.com` :

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  window.open(x, '_blank');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position:absolute;">
  Surf here:
  <input type="text" id="myText" value="">
    <br>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Load
        </button>
          <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

If you test here, you will get this error in console `Blocked opening 'http://google.com/' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set`, then put that in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = $("#myText").val();
  $( "#demo" ).html( x );
  window.open(x, '_blank');
}
```

use http or https in the input field. Tried it in JSBin, it works.

Also the quotation marks in your div look mispaced. Try this:

```
<div style="position:'absolute';">
Surf here:<input type="text" id="myText" value=""><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Load</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```